# GNU make path substitution (directory flattening)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that gives me the source files in a hierarchy.

```
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.c)
```

gives me

```
./src/main.c ./src/add/add.c ./src/sub/sub.c
```

I want to flatten the object files into a single "obj" directory.
Of course

```
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj)
```

gives me

```
./obj/main.obj ./obj/add/add.obj ./obj/sub/sub.obj
```

instead of desired

```
./obj/main.obj ./obj/add.obj ./obj/sub.obj
```

**Question:** How do I get rid of additional source directory levels?

Never had to use complex substitution so far. My intuitive try with additional "/%" in pattern

```
# won't work as expected:    
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj)
```

produces no meaningful result (${OBJS} becomes same as ${SRCS}).
All examples I found so far only have **single** occurance of "%" in match pattern.

```
MAK_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

SRC_DIR = $(MAK_DIR)./src
OBJ_DIR = $(MAK_DIR)./obj

# gives: ./src/main.c ./src/add/add.c ./src/sub/sub.c
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c $(SRC_DIR)/*/*.c)
# gives: ./obj/main.obj ./obj/add/add.obj ./obj/sub/sub.obj
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj)

.PHONY : all
all :
    @echo $(SRCS)
    @echo $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `notdir` function, and also `patsubst`, more powerful (and that I find easier to understand than the shorthand):

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj,$(notdir $(SRCS)))
```

But it is not the whole story because later on you will probably want to do something like:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
```

which will not work any more. Not mentioning the fact that you could have several source files with the same name in different directories. Assuming you do not have such names conflicts you can generate all your dependencies using `foreach-eval-call`:

```
MAK_DIR := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
SRC_DIR := $(MAK_DIR)./src
OBJ_DIR := $(MAK_DIR)./obj

SRCS := $(shell find $(MAK_DIR) -type f -name '*.c')
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

.PHONY: objs
objs: $(OBJS)

# $(1): source file
define DEP_rule
$(1)-obj := $$(patsubst %.c,$$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj,$$(notdir $(1)))
$(1)-dep := $$(patsubst %.c,$$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d,$$(notdir $(1)))

$$($(1)-obj): $(1) $$($(1)-dep)
endef
$(foreach src,$(SRCS),$(eval $(call DEP_rule,$(src))))
```

Just remember that the `DEP_rule` macro gets expanded twice, thus the `$$`.

Comment: Yep. Your code does the job. Thanks.
And you are right. Indeed my makefile got broken. I had everything in one place getting more and more sources.
So I wanted to move them in subdirectories. Of course my
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.obj : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(OBJ_DIR)/%.d
now is broken as it is missing the folder structure.
NB: naming is no problem due to naming convention though.

Comment: Well, there is a way using advanced features of GNU make. See my updated answer.